# How to find out which setup failed in Assert of `VerifyAll`?

Tags: moq, automocking

I am writing the unit test for a method. I have properly configured all the setups. While debugging unit test it works and returns values as expected. But in assertion it still throws false.

Therefore, I am not able to understand why does `VerifyAll` throws false all the time? How to find out which setup failed the VerifyAll assert?

Answer (score 0):

`VerifyAll` verifies that all your Setups were called. It sounds like you have a `Setup` that is not relevant to your test, hence your are getting the expected output, yet the `VerifyAll` fails because that `Setup` was never called.

When `VerifyAll` fails you will get an exception, and the reason is given there. For example, if I create an unused `Setup` in a test I get:

> Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched:
>   IMyClass m => m.MyMethod()